# JavaScript multiple forms using preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code in a jQuery document ready;

```
jQuery("#frmUpdateDet").submit(function (e) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './php/updateCred.php',
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery("#msg").empty();
                jQuery("#msg").append("<p>" + data + "</p>");
                jQuery("#msg").show().delay(800).fadeOut();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery("#frmUpdatePass").submit(function (e) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './php/updateCred.php',
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery("#msg").empty();
                jQuery("#msg").append("<p>" + data + "</p>");
                jQuery("#msg").show().delay(800).fadeOut();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

however when I submit the "frmUpdateDet" form, it doesn't redirect to my php script BUT when I submit my "frmUpdatePass" form it redirects to my php script... How is this even possible? my function is just a replica of the previous function ...

edit -- both of my HTML forms are added via JavaScript, one of the form is shown below - 
re-edit... my function

```
function accountSettingMenuClick($id){
// 1 = details
// 2 = security
// 3 = cloud settings

jQuery("#AD").css("text-decoration", "none");
jQuery("#AS").css("text-decoration", "none");
jQuery("#ACS").css("text-decoration", "none");

var cred;
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    url: './php/retrieve/getCred.php',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != "null") {
            cred = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    }
});

if($id == 1) {
    jQuery("#AD").css("text-decoration", "underline");
    var adHTML;
    if(cred == "null") {
        adHTML = "<p>Error! Contact Administrator</p>";
    } else {
        adHTML = "<form id='frmUpdateDet' action='./php/updateCred.php' method='POST'><table class='table'>" +
            "<tr> <td>Name: </td> <td><input class='mainInput' name='name' type='text' value='" + cred['credentials']['name'] + "' placeholder='" + cred['credentials']['name'] + "'/></td> </tr>" +
            "<tr> <td>Surname: </td> <td><input class='mainInput' name='surname' type='text' value='" + cred['credentials']['surname'] + "' placeholder='" + cred['credentials']['surname'] + "' /></td> </tr>" +
            "</table> <table class='table'><tr><td><input type='submit' value='Update' class='mainBtn'/></td></tr></table>  </form>";
    }
    jQuery("#content").append(adHTML);
} else if ($id == 2) {
    jQuery("#AS").css("text-decoration", "underline");
    var asHTML;
    if(cred == "null") {
        asHTML = "<p>Error! Contact Administrator</p>";
    } else {
        asHTML = "<form id='frmUpdatePass' action='./php/updateCred.php' method='POST'><table class='table'>" +
            "<tr> <td>Old Password: </td> <td><input class='mainInput' name='oldPass' type='password' placeholder='Current Password' required/></td> </tr>" +
            "<tr> <td>New Password: </td> <td><input class='mainInput' name='newPass' type='password' placeholder='New Password' required onchange='form.rPass.pattern = this.value;'/></td> </tr>" +
            "<tr> <td>Re-type New Password: </td> <td><input class='mainInput' id='rPass' type='password' placeholder='Re-type New Password' /></td> </tr>" +
            "</table> <table class='table'><tr><td><input type='submit' value='Update' class='mainBtn'/></td></tr></table>  </form>";
    }
    jQuery("#content").append(asHTML);
} else if ($id == 3) {
    jQuery("#ACS").css("text-decoration", "underline");
    var acsHTML;
    if(cred == "null") {
        acsHTML = "<p>Error! Contact Administrator</p>";
    } else {
        var show;
        var limit = cred['credentials']['limit'];
        if (limit > 5000) {
            show = limit/1024;
            show = show.toFixed(2);
            show = show + " GB";
        } else {
            show = limit;
            show = show + " MB";
        }

        acsHTML = "<form id='frmUpdateUpg'><table class='table'>" +
            "<tr> <td>Current Limit: </td> <td><input type='text' class='mainInput' style='border: none; border-bottom: 1px dashed black; width: 100px; text-align: center;' disabled value='" + show +"'></td> </tr>" +
            "</table> <table class='table'><tr><td><input type='submit' class='mainBtn' value='Upgrade'/></td></tr></table>  </form>";
    }
    jQuery("#content").append(acsHTML);
}
```

}

and my angular controller -

```
function AppSettingsCtrl($scope){
if (checkSession() == false){
    location = "#/";
} else {
    validateUI();
}

accountSettingMenuClick(1);

jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {
    jQuery("#AD").click(function () {
        jQuery("#content").empty();
        accountSettingMenuClick(1);
    });

    jQuery("#AS").click(function () {
        jQuery("#content").empty();
        accountSettingMenuClick(2);
    });

    jQuery("#ACS").click(function () {
        jQuery("#content").empty();
        accountSettingMenuClick(3);
    });

    jQuery("#frmUpdateDet").submit(function (e) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './php/updateCred.php',
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery("#msg").empty();
                jQuery("#msg").append("<p>" + data + "</p>");
                jQuery("#msg").show().delay(800).fadeOut();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    jQuery("#frmUpdatePass").submit(function (e) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './php/updateCred.php',
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                jQuery("#msg").empty();
                jQuery("#msg").append("<p>" + data + "</p>");
                jQuery("#msg").show().delay(800).fadeOut();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Errors in the console? Can you post the rest of the code including the HTML?

Comment: no errors in my console

Comment: General tip: if you must use HTML in strings (strongly recommend storing that in a dummy `script` element template), use single quotes on the outside so that the HTML attributes can have standard double-quotes.

Comment: Are both forms added/in place *before* the handler code is run?

Comment: Please show the HTML for the second form as well. The first one seems fine.

Comment: ^ thanks for the tip, but i got to much code now to start switching the quotes...

Comment: Unfortunately if you use single quotes for HTML attributes, your code will not be compatible with `a)` JSFiddle and `b)` some older browsers :(

Comment: that sucks.. the weirdest thing is that the first form submit function works, but the second doesnt... does it have anything to do with my function since i am appending my data?

Comment: Yes, if you add elements dynamically the event handlers will not connect to those new elements. Use delegated events instead (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention your elements are added dynamically. That usually means you need to use delegated event handlers:

### e.g.

```
jQuery(document).on("submit", "#frmUpdatePass", function (e) {
```

Delegated events listen at an ancestor, *then* apply the selector, *then* apply the function to any matching elements that generated the event. The elements do not need to exists at the time the handler is added.

*note: *as mentioned, you really need to use templates instead of HTML strings, or at least switch to single quotes so the HTML attributes will be double-quoted as expected* This will be a real problem for you when you want help on SO.

Here is an example that uses your HTML strings in templates instead and uses delegated event handlers:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/WpWz5/1/

The code to append template can replace any placeholder strings in the template as needed:

e.g.

```
 $('body').append($('#frmUpdateDettmp').html().replace("{surname}", surname).replace("{credentials}", credentials));
```

Although for multiple matches you need to use RegEx expressions with /g (global) in them.

Comment: I never used angular before.. and i was trying out the ng-view. i am creating mini projects to try out different ways.. how ever i tried your code and it didnt seem to work

Comment: "didn't seem to work" is not enough information :) You need to fill out that JSFiddle I provided with the rest of your code and test it there.

Comment: i have made some tweaks to your code and got it to work after researching a bit on delegates.. jQuery(document).delegate('#frmUpdateDet','submit', function (e) {}); this has seem to solve my problem :) thanks!

Comment: `delegate` is outdated. `on` is preferred. The test fiddle provided actually fires correctly, so you may just have a typo somewhere.

Comment: i am using a JSON object from my database to get the credentials btw.. but i have seen tutorials on angular documentation... I will try em out later on :)

Comment: I was not using angular... That is just your raw HTML strings in a dummy script block (so it is ignored by the browser, but still available). Much easier to maintain that way (and has double-quotes!) :)